# Wildcards in Powershell

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I am new to Powershell and am trying to incorporate wildcards. I am trying to add wildcards to the line

```
Add-AppxPackage –DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_3.8.8.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\appxmanifest.xml"
```

This works and installs Sticky Notes on the PC. However, the version of StickyNotes is always changing and running that line fails if the current version is not 3.8.8.0. Is there a way I can add a wildcard to have it install StickyNotes with any version? I have tried things such as

```
Add-AppxPackage –DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes*\appxmanifest.xml"
```

We are using this to install Microsoft applications for our employees without opening the Microsoft Store as we have it blocked.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Try using `Resolve-Path` to determine the path first? Something like `$AppPath = resolve-path "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes*x64*\appxmanifest.xml"`

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I bet `Get-AppxPackage` allows you to search for packages using wildcards ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres a thousand ways to skin a cat, this is how I would do it:

```
#grab all folders
$versionsFull=dir "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\"
$VersionsNumberOnly=@()
#isolate the version numbers
foreach($v in $versionsFull){
$VersionsNumberOnly+=$v.name.split("_")[1]
}
#find the newest
$newestVersion=$VersionsNumberOnly|sort -Descending|Select -first 1
$newestVersion
#add to path
Add-AppxPackage –DisableDevelopmentMode -register "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_$newestversion`_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\appxmanifest.xml"
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I was able to get this working. I was trying too hard to run everything in one command rather than breaking it down, but this has made it much clearer.